# order by a count property in an entity with a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EfCore 3 and I have an entity with a many to many relationship that looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    public List<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
    public int BarsCount => FooBars.Count();
}
```

**and I would like to know if it is possible to configure it so that this query would work:**

```
fooQuery.OrderBy(o => o.BarsCount)
```

right now I'm getting this error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Foo>.OrderBy(d => d.BarsCount)' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

if I use a `.ToList()` before calling `OrderBy` it works, but this is not a good solution because it will load the whole table before I get the change to call Skip and Take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate the `BarsCount` property into SQL. So instead you need to use the full expression:

```
var foos = context.Foos
    .OrderBy(d => d.FooBars.Count());
```

Comment: would it be possible to configure it so that it would do what you wrote automatically when calling `.OrderBy(o => o.BarsCount)`, the query is generated using dynamic linq, I'm not writing them manually

Comment: I doubt it, and honestly, I wouldn't have that count property in your entity class in the first place, for reasons like the problem you are seeing here.

Comment: But I guess it depends on how you are generating your dynamic Linq.

Comment: my code is generating the dynamic linq, so the alternative for me would be to find a way to call `Foobars.Count()` in dlinq